# Show only current atlas feature (line) within current atlas plot

Tags: qgis-3, line, atlas

I am using lines as atlas features so that I can rotate the view by the azimuth of the line.  How can I have only the current atlas feature printed on the current sheet?  I can see how "Within" would work for polygons but can't find a similar solution for a line feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to show only specific line(s) within atlas map and hide other lines. If so, you can achieve this using Rule-based Symbology.

- Make sure you have a unique ID for each line, and select the field that stores the ids as page name

[image]

- Use Rule-based Symbology and add expression: `$id = @atlas_featureid` and give it the symbol you like, and the another line with expression `$id != @atlas_featureid` and select `No pen` for `stroke style`, Apply and OK.

[image]

- When activating the Atlas in the Layout Manager, you will see only the line(s) with the selected IDs and other lines will be hidden.

[image]

[image]